# Is there a way to sign existing installers using install4j?

Tags: code-signing, install4j

I was wondering if install4j supports signing existing installers?

We have a release process which involves a manual step to get the password to sign the installers. We were hoping to build the installers,  test them, then if the tests pass and we are ready to release then sign them just before shipping them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible with install4j. You could of course sign the installers with external tools, but the included launchers would not be signed in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I was worried this would be the case. I guess we will end up trying to reimplment what install4j already does to do it.